# JQuery Programmatically adding articles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to programmatically add articles to my website and then add a random word to each article using Jquery. I am able to make all the articles but I am not able to add text to the articles. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/jquery.lorem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var colors = ["#CCCCCC", "#333333", "#990099"];
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

            $(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((Math.random() * 64) + 34) ; i++) {
                    $("#Inferface").append("<article class='box' style='background-color:" + colors[rand] + "'><span>" + i + "</span>");
                }
            });
            // This line below should be adding the random word to each of the articles

            $('.box').lorem({ type: 'words', amount: '1', ptags: false });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body id="Inferface">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the jQuery lorem plugin is correctly loaded in to your webpage?

Comment: yes, it works. lets say that i have a <div class="box"></div> it will display a word in the body.

Comment: See this fiddle with your code. Works just fine.
Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dVVHs/1/

Comment: That is werid, because i have ran it in chrome and explorer and I am just getting the i counter displaying

Comment: Re-edit your post to include the rest of your code. Might be something conflicting.

Comment: I added the entire source file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, It seems to me that the code is working with very few adjustments

```
$(function ()
{
        var colors = ["#CCCCCC", "#333333", "#990099"];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((Math.random() * 64) + 34) ; i++)
        {
           $("#Interface").append("<article class='box' style='background-color:" + colors[rand] + "'><span>" + i + "</span>");
        }
        // This line below should be adding the random word to each of the articles
        $('.box').lorem({ type: 'words', amount: '1', ptags: false});
});
```

.. you can check it out here :
[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gbymL/)

Comment: So it appears that the div you added made the difference? Do you know why that might be the case? Also, do you know why each article isn't a different color?

Comment: It could be due to some limitation of the lorem plugin in some environments .. it's hard to tell

Comment: I think the difference has to do with loading the script on  `$(document).ready` vs `$(window).load`. Your original code works if you change it to `$(window).load`